# "Non-static method requires a target" exception after Unity upgrade

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After upgrading Unity from 2019.4.13f to 2019.4.29f1, I get this exception when I hit play in the editor or open a scene:

"System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires a target."

At a C# level, I understand the meaning of that error. If the problem were in my code, I could fix it pretty simply.

But figuring out which thing in Unity or 3rd-party assets needs to be fixed... huh. I don't know.

The call stack on the error seems pretty generic:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires a target.
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0004c] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies.ProcessInitializeOnLoadMethodAttributes () [0x00047] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorAssemblies.cs:154 
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadMethodAttributes () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorAssemblies.cs:158)
```

I checked in the editor.log, found the same exception, but gained no insights from the logging before and after it.

How to fix this? Or even troubleshoot it? My best idea so far is creating a copy of the project, and experimenting with deleting third party assets to narrow the cause. But that is so time-consuming, and maybe it's not a third party asset.

Comment: I'd search for things using the `InitializeOnLoadMethod` attribute and see where that leads. Removing stuff to narrow down the problem shouldn't take that long assuming the project is in source control so you can easily bring things back.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @derHugo I don't know what code I would show. The exception is thrown inside Unity code while it's attempting to initialize a different object that is unknown to me.